# Declare the type of a variable separate from destructuring initialization

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I'm destructuring a bunch of props from a useHook(), and want to declare the type of one of them:

```js
const { foo, bar, complexObject } = useSomething();
// TODO: declare `complexObject` to be of some type
```

Alternatives I've tried:

1. Initialize `complexObject` with `let`, which will generate a warning because it's never changed later
2. Repeat the list and declare `complexObject`:

```js
const { foo, bar, complexObject }: { foo, bar, complexObject: SomeType } = useSomething();
```

That repeats all other constants, and I'm only interested in declaring `complexObject`.

Comment: How `useSomething` is defined? If it will have appropriate return type - you won't need to define anything manually

Comment: @Aleksey: good point, it's various hooks. Sometimes the types are vague and don't help. For example, `{ ..., errors } = useForm()` from [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/api#useForm). I need to later access `errors.myInputId.message` for example, which complains "TS2339: Property 'myInputId' does not exist on type 'DeepMap{ name: string; }, FieldError>[]'."

Comment: I see, but I don't think it is possible (at least now). Regrading `useForm` - I'm not familiar with the library, but from quick look it seems you can help it to return proper type by providing `FormValues` generic parameter (e,g, `const { errors } = useForm<{ myInputId: string }>();` then `errors.myInputId` will be resolved to ` FieldError | undefined`)

Answer (score 0):

The hooks take generics. For example you can do `useState<MyType>()`